# Yoast SEO 3.1: Improved snippet editor and primary category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, yoast

My primary category is not working , it is working according to alphabetically selection.
How it is working and what i do for this please help.

please see widget image to understand
https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/9658774/17168795/a82c8c24-53e4-11e6-8ef4-36815073cd4e.png